# Split and remove particular value in href attribute and add new value using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have splitted the value in href attribute of a tag.

i splitted the value but i cannot remove the values and append new into it.

My HTML code is

```
<a class="chapter_video" href="http://localhost/SVE128-portal2/public/video/9/25"></a>
```

And my jquery is

```
 var new = 4;
 var video_url = $('.chapter_video');
 var href = video_url.attr("href");
 //splitting value of href                  
 var split = href.split("/");
 if(split[7] !== undefined){                         
     href.remove(split[7]);
 }

 video_url.attr('href', video_url.attr('href') + '/'+ new);
```

I have tried

```
 var remove = href.replace('split[7]', '')
```

instead of `href.remove(split[7]);`

Comment: Are you trying to remove the last part, or always a specific part?

Comment: Specific part @DouwedeHaan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Old version:

While the answer of Muhammad Qasim fixes your problem, it doesn't take in account the possibility that the value of `split[7]` could occur multiple times in the string. I believe this fixes your problem the correct way:

```
var new = 4;
var video_url = $('.chapter_video');
var href = video_url.attr("href");
// Splitting value of href                  
var split = href.split("/");
if(split[7] !== undefined){                         
    // This removes the last item of the array
    // You could also use .pop() which also removes the last part of the array
    split.splice(-1, 1);
}
// Pastes all the array parts back together (opposite of split)
href = split.join('/')

video_url.attr('href', href + '/'+ new);
```

### New version

After some more tests, it occured to me that splice wouldn't be the smartest way to do this. Replacing the value in the URL directly would be better:

```
var new_id = 4;
var video_url = $('.chapter_video');
var href = video_url.attr("href");
// Splitting value of href         
var split = href.split("/");
if(split[7] !== undefined){
    split[7] = new_id;
}
else {
    // If there isn't a 8th item in the array, add it to the end
    split.push(new_id)
}
// Pastes all the array parts back together (opposite of split)
href = split.join('/')

video_url.attr('href', href);
```

Comment: Its Working.. Thank you so much

Comment: @Vinothini I added some more information and a newer version. My old version would break if your url would contain more parts after the 25 in your example url.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var video_url = $('.chapter_video');
 var href = video_url.attr("href");               
 var split = href.split("/");
 var usethis;
 var addthis = 4;
 if(split[7] !== undefined){                         
     usethis = split.slice(0, -1); 
 }
console.log(usethis.join("/")+ "/"+ addthis)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="chapter_video" href="http://localhost/SVE128-portal2/public/video/9/25"></a>
```

1. To remove the last part use `.splice()`
2. Connect again using join("/")
3. Then add the new value with "/"

Comment: splice(0, -1) doesn't remove anything on my end. I believe you mean `splice(-1)`?

Comment: @DouwedeHaan that is what i been using and it does remove.

Comment: What browser are you using? When I test it with Google Chrome (56) it doesn't do anything.

Comment: @DouwedeHaan `Version 57.0.2987.133`

Comment: My final answer (newest version) doesn't use splice. It occurred to me that there could be more url parts after the id, which would break both of our script. But I'm going to look into the difference in the splice version. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is simple:

```
 var newUrl = 4;
 var video_url = $('.chapter_video');
 var href = video_url.attr("href");
 //splitting value of href                  
 var split = href.split("/");
 if(split[7] !== undefined){

     href = href.replace(split[7], '');
 }

 video_url.attr('href', href + newUrl);
```

Comment: No its appending as a new value not removing

Comment: I have updated my answer..check it clearly..especially the last line

Comment: All are working fine but its appending extra slash **http://localhost/SVE128-portal2/public/video/9//26**

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't use new keyword for variable names
2. Where is no remove function for string.(use replace('val','') for remove)

   ```
   var _new = 4;
   var video_url = $('.chapter_video'); 
   var href = video_url.attr("href").toString(); 
   //splitting value of href       
   var split = href.split("/");
   console.log(split);
   if(split[7] !== undefined){                         
        href.replace(split[7],'');  
   }

   video_url.attr('href', video_url.attr('href') + '/'+ _new); 
   console.log(video_url.attr('href') + '/'+ _new);
   ```

Answer (score 0):

If the url is generated from server side then this way of solving problem is not future proof, what if url changes overtime?
More accurate way is to have static part of url in different attribute:

```
<a 
  class="chapter_video" 
  href="http://localhost/SVE128-portal2/public/video/9/25" 
  data-href="http://localhost/SVE128-portal2/public/video"
  data-pid="9"
  data-id="25"
>
</a>

var new = 4;
var video_url = $('.chapter_video');
var href_part = video_url.attr("data-href");
var pid = video_url.attr("data-pid");

video_url.attr('href', href_part + '/'+ pid + '/' + new);
```